# Fiware idm does not send "I accept" link for confirmation for creating user

Tags: fiware

I have installed fiware-idm keyrock(7.0.1) with docker. I am able to login with admin user. However, while creating a new user, the user is created, but on receiving confirmation link "I accept" link is not present. "I accept" is given as text and as a result, the user is not able to confirm. Kindly provide if anything else has to be added after docker installation of keylock.

These are my docker logs for fiware idm where I can't find anything.

```
GET / 200 23.763 ms - 6132
GET /javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js 304 1.796 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-tour.min.css 304 14.430 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/jquery.Jcrop.css 304 14.750 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-select.min.css 304 14.332 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap.min.js 304 0.481 ms - -
GET /javascripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js 304 0.470 ms - -
GET /javascripts/jquery.bootpag.min.js 304 0.353 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap-select.min.js 304 1.490 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap-tour.min.js 304 1.412 ms - -
GET /javascripts/handle_csrf_token.js 304 1.477 ms - -
GET /javascripts/tour.js 304 1.573 ms - -
GET /javascripts/others/see_password.js 304 0.396 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 742.032 ms - -
GET /img/keyrock01.png 304 2.105 ms - -
GET /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff 304 2.105 ms - -
GET /fonts/font-awesome/fa-solid-900.woff2 304 1.105 ms - -
GET /confirmation/ 200 6.843 ms - 3859
GET /javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js 304 0.378 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/jquery.Jcrop.css 304 0.531 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-tour.min.css 304 0.486 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-select.min.css 304 3.070 ms - -
GET /javascripts/jquery.bootpag.min.js 304 2.317 ms - -
GET /javascripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js 304 3.049 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap.min.js 304 3.143 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap-select.min.js 304 0.360 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap-tour.min.js 304 1.119 ms - -
GET /javascripts/handle_csrf_token.js 304 1.020 ms - -
GET /javascripts/tour.js 304 1.017 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 8.628 ms - 435232
GET /img/keyrock01.png 304 0.384 ms - -
GET /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff 304 0.462 ms - -
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `description`, `website`, `image`, `gravatar`, `email`, `salt`, `password`, `date_password`, `enabled`, `admin`, `starters_tour_ended`, `eidas_id`, `extra`, `scope` FROM `user` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`email` = 'kushsrivastava.123@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): UPDATE `user_registration_profile` SET `activation_key`='z14selz8lef',`activation_expires`='2018-12-18 18:00:10' WHERE `user_email` = 'kushsrivastava.123@gmail.com'
POST /confirmation 302 81.498 ms - 66
GET /auth/login 200 6.714 ms - 6400
GET /javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js 304 0.964 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/jquery.Jcrop.css 304 0.452 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-tour.min.css 304 0.773 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2.765 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-select.min.css 304 0.401 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap.min.js 304 0.695 ms - -
GET /javascripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js 304 0.728 ms - -
GET /javascripts/jquery.bootpag.min.js 304 0.636 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap-select.min.js 304 0.614 ms - -
GET /javascripts/bootstrap-tour.min.js 304 0.333 ms - -
GET /javascripts/handle_csrf_token.js 304 0.378 ms - -
GET /javascripts/tour.js 304 0.347 ms - -
GET /javascripts/others/see_password.js 304 0.337 ms - -
GET /img/keyrock01.png 304 0.441 ms - -
GET /fonts/neotechstd/neotechstd-regular.woff 304 0.810 ms - -
GET /fonts/font-awesome/fa-solid-900.woff2 304 0.805 ms - -
```

Comment: Release **7.0.1** is comng up to a year old and somewhat out of date. I would suggest trying the latest [7.5.1](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/releases/tag/7.5.1) release and seeing if your issue was a bug that has been subsequently fixed - maybe there was a problem in the eMail template perhaps.

Comment: Where can i find the docker image for 7.5.1??

Comment: You can download it from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/idm/builds) or build directly from [source](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/blob/master/extras/docker/Dockerfile)